# Spring MVC - HTTP 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported loading static CSS File

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I have read several post in stackoverflow about configurations and mappings to serve
static content like js and css but I can not make it work.

I have the following files:

-> POM.XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>es.landeSoft</groupId>
        <artifactId>MvcTesting</artifactId>
        <name>SpringMVCTesting</name>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <properties>
            <java-version>1.6</java-version>
            <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
            <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
            <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Spring -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                     </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- AspectJ -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
            </dependency>   

            <!-- Logging -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.15</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- @Inject -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
                <version>1</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Servlet -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Test -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.7</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>        
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <additionalProjectnatures>
                            <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                        </additionalProjectnatures>
                        <additionalBuildcommands>
                            <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                        </additionalBuildcommands>
                        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                        <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                        <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

--> WEB.XML

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

--> SERVLET-CONTEXT.XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

        <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->


            <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
        <mvc:annotation-driven />   

        <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/ by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->

        <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


        <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean>

        <context:component-scan base-package="es.landeSoft.MvcTesting" />

    </beans>
```

As you can see in servlet-context I have declared the following line:

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

And I have created a css file inside:

**src/Main/webapp/resources/css/styles.css**

Inside my jsp I reference it like:

```
href="<c:url value="/resources/css/styles.css" />"
```

It renders like this:

```
   <link href="/MvcTesting/resources/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"/>
```

But I am getting :

```
GET http://localhost:8081/MvcTesting/resources/css/styles.css 405 (Method not allowed)
```

I tried adding servlet-mappings in web.xml but I want to make it work using the
new tag

And It works, but I do not want to do it like this. the

When tomcat is starting I can read the following line:

```
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
```

.

[image]

EDIT:

I'm trying using:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

NO luck

Comment: Can you post your `web.xml` file?

Comment: sorry I forgot. Updated

Comment: I am having trouble seeing your problem.  I have configured many projects in the exact manner you provided.  Does this occur for all resource files?  One thing I have noticed is that you need to make sure the XML files do not wrap any configuration, extra whitespace in those files causes issues and they are a bear to detect.

Comment: I see the following line: INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'. Do I need to register the ResourceHttpRequestHandler somewhere?. Thanks for your comment Kevin. This is driving me nuts

Comment: Updated the web.xml. It was not showing.

Comment: Did you have any luck figuring this out?  I just got back from the gym and was going to investigate.

Comment: I made a working example for you and posted it on GitHub see the updated answer.

Comment: Does the package `es.landeSoft.MvcTesting` contain anything we should know about?

Comment: Do zou have by any chance some of the controllers mapped to / or /*?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, below code, worked for me.
Try to add this to your web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

A `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` class' instance cannot produce a 405 Method Not Allowed response.

You either have a security layer wrapping your requests (doubtful) or you have a `@Controller` handler method mapped to `/` or `/*` that handles a request method other than `GET`.

Since `@RequestMapping` handler methods have higher priority than any `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` mappings, the handler mapped to `/*` which can handle `/MvcTesting/resources/css/styles.css` will be used for handling that request and will respond with 405 because the path is good but the request method isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can try mapping `<url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>` with `DispatcherServlet` in `web.xml` like

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I have read this would make the servlet to serve the static content and there is not need for this. THat is why the <mvc:resource was created

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may not be accessing the `.jsp` file through a controller.  Try adding in this controller and accessing through the `.jsp` through this mapping.

**Controller**

```
package es.landeSoft.MvcTesting;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String login(){
        return "login";     
    }
}
```

To see a full working example view this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/kmb385/SpringMvcResourcesExample).

Comment: Can you explain why this would make a difference?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Your right this wouldn't.  I think the provided example could be of value though.